# Second order differential equation, two solutions given?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The results of a **second order differential equation** are two linear independent function $$y1=2-x-e^{-x};  \quad y2=1+x-e^{x}$$

The result of this differential equation which traverses the point $$T(0,1)$$where $$y^{\prime}(0)=\sqrt{3} $$is:

[image]

I've never seen something even similar to this. My attempt was to "guess" the solution based on the results:

- $$y1 --> A+(Bx+C)+De^x$$
- $$y2 --> E+(Fx+G)+He^x$$ 
  after that I would take the derivatives of that, but I'm pretty sure that I messed something. Any help on this?

Comment: The general solution y is a linear combination of the two given. This introduces two unknown constants. You are told that y(0) = 1 and the value of y'(0), which will let you calculate these constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When solving a second degree equation, you can usually find two linearly independent solutions. They have done this for you, so you don't have to worry about that part. You're not even told what the equation is.

The next step involves finding *which* linear combination of the two solutions goes through the right point and has the correct slope. In other words, you're supposed to find $A$ and $B$ such that $Ay_1+By_2$ has the prescribed properties.

Comment: Should I take the derivative of y1 and y2 in order to plug in sqrt(3)?

Comment: Yes, that's how it's usually done. In other words, solve the system of equations given by $Ay_1(0)+By_2(0)=1$ and $Ay_1'(0)+By_2(0)=\sqrt3$ for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: For the second coefficient, B, I get $$+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ but for the first equation I get A=1 but it should be something else, in other words, A should involve sqrt(3) to match one of the results from the table.

Comment: I also get $y_1(0)=1, y_2(0)=0$, which makes $A=1$. That makes me think there is a typo somewhere, either in your textbook, or that you copied the problem wrong.

Comment: It's from the exam, here is the link. It's a big exam and I doubt they get there results wrong. Questions number 4) https://www.fer.unizg.hr/_download/repository/159hr.pdf

Comment: You've written $y_2=1+x-e^x$, while the exam says $1+x+e^x$. That should solve your conundrum and let you get a result that agrees with one of the alternatives.

Comment: So sorry for that Sir. Sorry for taking too much of your time. The result is c.tnxx!